# Load Avro file to GCS with nested record using customized column name

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

I was trying to load an Avro file with nested record. One of the record was having a union of schema. When loaded to BigQuery, it created a very long name like com_mycompany_data_nestedClassname_value on each union element. That name is long. Wondering if  there is a way to specify name without having the full package name prefixed.

For example. The following Avro schema

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "EventRecording",
    "namespace": "com.something.event",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "eventName",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "eventTime",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "userId",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "eventDetail",
            "type": [
                {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "Network",
                    "namespace": "com.something.event",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "hostName",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ipAddress",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "DiskIO",
                    "namespace": "com.something.event",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "path",
                            "type":  "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "bytesRead",
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Came up with
[image]

Is that possible to make the long field name like **eventDetail.com_something_event_Network_value** to be something like **eventDetail.Network**

Answer (score 1):

Avro loading is not as flexible as it should be in BigQuery (basic example is that it does not support load a subset of the fields (reader schema). Also, renaming of the columns is not supported today in BigQuery [refer here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas). Only options are recreate your table with the proper names (create a new table from your existing table) or recreate the table from your previous table

Comment: Looks like it's not documented, but you can actually specify a schema when load Avro files to load a subset of the fields. This also applies if you're loading to an existing table whose schema is a subset of the Avro files. Only the fields in the specified/table schema will be loaded.

Comment: that is interesting. do you have an example how load data with a subset of the schema?

Comment: This is schema from a sample Avro file. It represents a complex number with two fields re and im.  

`{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "cpx",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "re",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "re field doc."
  }, {
    "name" : "im",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "im field doc."
  } ]
}`  

This command loads just the re field:  

`bq load --source_format=AVRO dataset.table path/to/file.avro 're:integer'`  

The table will be created with just one field, re:integer.